# asp.net handler not picking up case sensitive

Tags: asp.net, .net, handler, asp.net-4.0

I have this handler in my web.config:

```
  <add name="handler1" path="*.jpg" verb="*" type="ImageHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
```

Problem is the path is case sensitive. I want this handler to also pickup path like *.JPG. Is there any way to make the above line case insensitive?

Comment: I believe that this is runs on unix, and on unix the files are case sensitive (or am I wrong ?)

Comment: @Aristos: I am running on Windows only.

Answer (score 0):

As a quick fix, you can have a copy of this handler with path="*.JPG"